# NestJS-Telegraf Telegram bot only handles one request at a time

Tags: nestjs, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I started building a simple telegram bot using nestjs-telegraf package.
Following the docs, I created the basic AppUpdate service:

```
@Update()
@Injectable()
export class AppUpdate {
  @Command('random')
  async onRandom(@Ctx() ctx: Context) {
     const resp = await asyncRequestToGetData(ctx.message.text);
     await ctx.reply(resp);
  }
}
```

And provided it like this in app.module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TelegrafModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        token: configService.get<string>('TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    HttpModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppUpdate, ...],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The `asyncRequestToGetData` is an http call that sometimes takes 10 seconds or more.
And for some reason if another user tries to call the same command on the bot while request is processing, the `onRandom` is not called until the processing is finished.
Basically, not able to handle concurrent requests.

Was not able to find the reason/solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar issue and managed to resolve it. The problem occurs when you use await inside the command handler, which causes the bot to wait for the completion of the current command before processing the next one. To handle multiple requests concurrently, you can change the command handler as follows:

Before:

```
@Command('test')
async onTestCommand(ctx: any): Promise<any> {
    console.log('test command');
    await this.testTimeout();
    
    return;
}
```

After:

```
@Command('test')
async onTestCommand(ctx: any): Promise<any> {
    console.log('test command');
    this.testTimeout().then(() => {
        ctx.reply('test');
    });

    return;
}
```

By removing the await and using .then() instead, the command handler no longer waits for the testTimeout() function to finish before processing the next request. This change allows the bot to handle multiple requests concurrently.